# Webpack with optimization enabled breaks my extension

Tags: webpack, google-chrome-extension

I develop a React-based Chrome extension using TypeSript and Webpack. During the implementation of the latest feature, our extension stopped working. The background script is not loaded anymore but Chrome reports no error.
Here is what I found until now:

- If I use Webpack in production mode then the extension is working fine but doesn't work in development mode. No warnings, no compile error. So the code should be fine.
- If I remove the call of the latest function (Just a simple fetch to save data to our server) then the extension works again. (background script loads).
- It is strange, but if I remove the latest function then the generated code is bigger (56kb) and if I put it back the code becomes smaller (37kb).
- If I remove the complete optimization block from my Wepback config then the extension works again.

Additional info:

- Originally I used Webpack 5.51.1 but the same error occurres with 5.55.1
- I use Chrome 94 on Windows 10
- I use TypesScript 4.4.2

webpack.common.js

```
const path = require('path');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = {
    watch: true,
    target: 'web',
    entry: {
        background: path.resolve('src/background/background.ts'),
        popup: path.resolve('src/popup/popup.tsx'),
        options: path.resolve('src/options/options.tsx'),
        content: path.resolve('src/content/content.tsx'),
        tab: path.resolve('src/tab/tab.tsx'),
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    resolve: {
        symlinks: false,
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                //use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"], // Inserts CSS into JavaScript
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'], // Creates separate CSS file
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                include: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    transpileOnly: true,
                },
            },
        ],
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: 'all',
            // This block makes a dedicated vendor bundle that contains the react code or exactly everything from the node_modules folder
            cacheGroups: {
                vendor: {
                    chunks: 'initial',
                    test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
                    name: 'vendor',
                    enforce: true,
                },
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'static/[name].css',
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin({
            cleanStaleWebpackAssets: false, // Automatically remove all unused webpack assets on rebuild
        }),
        new CopyPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from: path.resolve('src/static/images'),
                    to: path.resolve('dist/static/images'),
                },
                {
                    from: path.resolve('src/static/audio'),
                    to: path.resolve('dist/static/audio'),
                },
                {
                    from: path.resolve('src/manifest.json'),
                    to: path.resolve('dist/manifest.json'),
                },
            ],
        }),
        ...getHtmlPlugins(['popup', 'options', 'tab']),
    ],
};

function getHtmlPlugins(chunks) {
    return chunks.map(
        (chunk) =>
            new HtmlPlugin({
                template: `src/${chunk}/${chunk}.html`,
                filename: `${chunk}.html`,
                chunks: [chunk],
            })
    );
}
```

webpack.dev.js

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
});
```

webpack.prod.js

```
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const common = require("./webpack.common.js");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: "production",
});
```

Comment: did you find a solution? I have a very similar issue